# Query on jsonb array

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

I have this kind of json array and i want to check *stringValue* inside value array is null or not plus i want to check it with its *id* and **fielddata** is column name

```
[
  {
    "name": "50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1",
    "value": {
      "stringValue": null
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "bb127e8284c84692aa217539c4312394",
    "value": {
      "dateValue": 1549065600
    }
  }
]
```

query is:

```
select * 
from field 
WHERE (fielddata->>'name') = '50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1' 
   AND fielddata->'value'->>'stringValue' IS NOT NULL;
```

***and I want use this query in laravel5.7***

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result = \DB::table('field')->where('name', "50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1" )->where('value', $stringValue)->get();

if(isset($result)){
    foreach($result as $res){
        if(isset($res['value']->stringValue)){
            // not null case
        }else{
            // null case
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within a SQL query, I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.fielddata) as j(e)
              where e ->> 'name' = '50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1' 
                and e -> 'value' ->> 'stringValue' is not null);
```

The exists sub-query will check every array element and see if at least one element has the specified name and a non-null `stringValue`. The query will then return the complete row from the table that fulfills the condition.

Online example: https://rextester.com/AGGJNR88809